# Call mainwindows from UserControl

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, user-controls, mainwindow

I have a Window(mainwindows.xaml) where there's a label.Now,i've created a UserControl(Just a basic button)..On `Window_load`,i'm adding the UserControl in a canvas(in mainwindow) using this :

```
Dim con as new myUserControl

Canvas.Children.Add(con)
```

Now What i want is,when i click the UserControl,the label will be hidden..How do i do this ??

I've tried creating a **WPF CUSTOM CONTROL LIBRARY** but don't know how to work with it ??

Comment: Go, so you also create custom controls and class libraries in C #.
Then we have something in common ;-)

Comment: I like it, so I upvote ;-)

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán , thanks man ..... but mind if i ask, what did u like about the qs ?

Comment: owwwww.....u are the guy !!! i just saw ur profile and remembered who u are man .... tnx anyway ...cheers

Comment: Then you had forgotten who I was, go, and I worried ;-)

Comment: i didn't get that ?? u mean i left SO ? that's what u thought ?

Comment: That I like?
Apart from that we have something in common, I learned that WPF can also be programmed in VB, which I thought until now that only could be in C #

Comment: No, I just thought that you thought I left

Comment: LMAO No.......hey, if u want, you can learn about WPF from me :) ... u can be friends on skype bro :)

Comment: or maybe SO chat ?

Comment: I thank you, but unfortunately I do not use Skipe

Comment: But I use Facebook, Twitter, Whatsapp ...

Comment: anyways......u can still use SO chat..but ur wish :) ..... i love spreading knowledge :)

Comment: Interesting, I'm interested in learning WPF, because I found out that it works for elegant interfaces and that it's easier than WinForms

Comment: join me on FB and i'll show u what i've done with WPF !! hope that it'll blow u LOL

Comment: Well, what will I do, em, and what about Twitter and WhatsApp?
Do you use them?

Comment: whatsapp,i do ,twitter, i don't :( .... and hey,i've given u my fb link ,it is better not to talk about these things here, rather let's open a chat , shall we ?

Comment: Well, I'll join

Comment: Am, and that we can also talk on WhatsApp to Facebbok?

for WhatsApp you can easily share images, videos, audio, etc.

Comment: [join the chat man](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168580/new-chat)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168581/discussion-between-hector-manuel-martinez-duran-and-zack-raiyan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself....Guess that was really easy.In usercontrol,just used this :

```
   Dim hm As MainWIndow = Window.GetWindow(Me)
   hm.Lbl1.Visibility=Visibility.Hidden
```

Comment: That's pretty horrible code really.  For a start, it requires `Option Strict Off`.  The UC shouldn't have to have such specific knowledge of the window it's on.  The correct way to do that is for the UC to raise an event and for the window to handle that event and hide the `Label` itself.

Comment: What do you not understand about the information you found when you looked for yourself?